# Website Layout height problems what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, sass

**Hello everyone.**

Since 3 Day's i'm trying to find a solution for my problem.
I'm making a Portfolio website with a fixed header, and a fixed sidebar.
In the content container i have multiple sections which are 100% of the parent div, later i'll add a snap scrolling effect so everything looks cool, i already got this working and all is fine.

*The Problem:*

All the sections needs to stay at the same height, but when i put a lot content inside a section, all sections getting bigger - but i want the content of the section to overflow:scroll so i can scroll inside the section and when i reached the bottom i want to scroll to the next section.

Second Problem:
When the whole window gets smaller in height i want the .site to overflow:scroll

This is how it should look like:
[image: Look here]

But when the inside of a section is higher than the section self:
[image: Look here]

Here is a code of a similar layout that i'm using on my homepage:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 100vh;
}

.site {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red ;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
}
.main {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    
}
.sidebar {}
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: blueviolet;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex: 1;
    
}

.section {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    
}
.section:last-child{
    background: blue
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="site">
            <div class="header">header</div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="sidebar">sidebar1</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="section">Now i want the content inside here to overflow inside of this section, but the section has to keep the same height.<br>You can see the Problem if you run this emmet: <h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1><h1>Overflow</h1></div>
                    <div class="section">section</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar">sidebar2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a image of the design i created that describes the problem:
[image: Layout image]

If someone could help me it would be amazing.

Thank you and have a nice weekend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've recreated your example. Used some different tags, but those are just semantics. With this structure only 4 css rules are very important, the rest is just for styling. I've put some emphasis on those important styles.

In this solution you are recreating a site that makes use of the full viewport but not more then that. In other words use 100vh. After that you want just a small part of the page to scroll. As you've set a height to that part now it will be scrollable.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*important*/
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px; /*important*/
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px); /*important*/
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

aside{
  padding: 0 2em;
}

section {
  overflow-y: scroll; /*important*/
}

article {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>HEADER</p>
</header>

<main>
  <aside>sidebar</aside>
  <section>
    <p>Now i want the content inside here to overflow inside of this section, but the section has to keep the same height. You can see the Problem if you run this emmet:</p>
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p></article>
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p></article>
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p></article>
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p></article>
  </section>
  <aside>sidebar</aside>
</main>
```

### EDIT

So at first I tried to answer your request with the scrollbar in section with all the content. However after your response to the above solution I like to suggest something else. One that fits the user experience a bit better and is still true to your last design. The big difference. We make the header and sidebars fixed and let the rest of the page grow normally. That way the user uses it's regular scrollbar from the browser and the header and sidebars will still stay in view.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*important*/
}

header {
  /*important*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
  
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

aside {
  /*important*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 75px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sidebar-left {
  left: 0;
}

.sidebar-right {
  right: 0;
}

main {
  /*important*/
  position: absolute; 
  top: 100px;
  left: 75px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  min-height: calc(100% - 100px);
  
  border: 2px solid red;
}

article {
  /*important*/
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Fixed elements -->
<header>HEADER</header>
<aside class="sidebar-left">sidebar</aside>
<aside class="sidebar-right">sidebar</aside>
  
<<main>
    <p>Now i want the content inside here to overflow inside of this section, but the section has to keep the same height. You can see the Problem if you run this emmet:</p>
    
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p></article>
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some content</p></article>
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p></article>
    <article><h1>Article title</h1><p>Some content</p></article>
  
 </main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, i understand but now i want the articles to be 100% height of their parent section and if the content inside of an article, the section needs to stay at the same height and the content inside of it has to be scrollable.

Second problem: If the sidebar has alot of content (a navigation) and the users window gets smaller in height, the whole body should scroll but the articles and the section needs to stay at full height

Comment: Okay so the last part of your comment wasn't really clear to me. But I've included a different way in an edit in my answer. Maybe that's something you can work with?

Comment: Now you understanding the problem, the last important thing is now scrolling inside the articles i dont know if that will work with your solution. Do you have discord ?

Comment: I don't. Last edit. All articles are now have a height from 350px for example. But the second article has content that's larger. Because of the `overflow-y: auto;` that article will be scrollable now, thus keeping the height of the articles all the same.

Comment: Bro i want to say thank you, i got it. The overflow-y on the sidebars was the solution.
May all your wishes come true my brother :D

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, add a fixed height to your sections and `overflow-y: scroll;` and should get what you want